# IntelliJ run context for JUnit TestTemplates

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, junit5

In JUnit 5 you can define your own test template and bind it to an annotation. 
Instead of @Test or @ParameterizedTest now I can use my own test annotaion @MyTest(...)

The problem is that Intellij does not recognize this annotation as JUnit test annotation thus does not give me the option to run/debug this test.

Can I extend this list of annotations that tells IntelliJ this is a test?

Picture on the left is a standard test where the context shows a run function.
Picture on the right shows my template which works perfectly just the context does not recognize it as a test.

[image: with context]
[image: context not recognized]

My test template looks like this:

```
@Target(
    AnnotationTarget.ANNOTATION_CLASS,
    AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION
)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)
@TestTemplate
@ExtendWith(ScTestExtension::class)
annotation class ScTest(
 // ... some properties  
)



class ScTestExtension : TestTemplateInvocationContextProvider {

    override fun supportsTestTemplate(context: ExtensionContext): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun provideTestTemplateInvocationContexts(extensionContext: ExtensionContext): Stream<TestTemplateInvocationContext> {
         // ... return invocation context
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you annotate `ScTest` with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`?

Comment: Did you annotate `ScTest` with `@Test` or `@ParameterizedTest`?

Comment: @Sormuras yes retention policy is set to runtime and annotated with Test or other known annotations but it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your `ScTest.java` should look similar to this one:

```java
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Test
public @interface ScTest {}
```

Derived from https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-meta-annotations

IIRC, IDEA and other IDEs look for an instance of [Testable](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/commons/annotation/Testable.html) to display the "Run..." icon. But normally, you shouldn't use that annotation directly. It should suffice to have it meta-annotated with `@Test`, `@TestTemplate`, or friends.

Here's another example using `@TestTemplate` that worked (at least, two years ago): [CartesianProductTest.java](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/master/junit5-jupiter-extensions/src/main/java/com/example/cartesian/CartesianProductTest.java#L23-L27)

```java
@TestTemplate
@ExtendWith(CartesianProductProvider.class)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CartesianProductTest {...}
```

Here is how *"IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 EAP (Community Edition) Build #IC-193.4386.10, built on October 9, 2019"* shows the usage of the `@CartesianProductTest` annotation today:

[image]

*Perhaps you need to switch to dark mode...*

Comment: Can you share more code - a minimal not working example perhaps?

Comment: Thanks @Sormuras, my code is almost the same as in this example. The only thing i am starting to doubt is, I am using Kotlin and not java. Do you have a Kotlin example?

Comment: My workaround for now is to additionaly put @TestTemplate to the test. This way it gets highlighted. But we can do better than that